# Set sequential number in mysql table only where rows have same value

Tags: mysql, join, row

I have a table in which a new entree gets a number 0, and a status of unpublished. Users can publish or unpublish rows. When they do, the published row should get a number that's consecutive, but the unpublished rows should be skipped. Like this:

```
status      | number
=============================
unpublished | 0
published   | 1
unpublished | 0
unpublished | 0
published   | 2
published   | 3
unpublished | 0
published   | 4
```

Right now I use:

```
mysql_query("update albums 
join (SELECT @i:=0) t
SET id =(@i:=@i+1)");
```

When a user publishes something, but that will add consecutive number to all rows.
I need something like the above, but with some sort of WHERE = published statement in it, but I don;t know how.
What solution should I look into?

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: "published row should get a number that's consecutive" Why?

Comment: Maybe this was the correct answer .. I 'need' a consecutive number, to number all entrees. But I'd be better of to do this in PHP afte retrieving the results, instead of in the database itself..

Comment: My comment above states true when it's just one instance in which I need some row of number, but in different instances it seemes better to have a number really attached to an entree, database side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an IF in the UPDATE statement:-

```
UPDATE albums 
JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) t
SET id = IF(status='published', @i:=@i+1, 0)
```

However this is not going to consistently work as I think you want I suspect without an ORDER BY clause (update does support and order clause).

EDIT - further info as requested:-

Albums is a MySQL table. The UPDATE query in MySQL does support the ORDER BY clause (to update records in a particular order), but only for queries where there is only a single table. In this query a sub query is joined to the albums table (ie, `JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) t` ); even though this is not actually a table it seems MySQL regards it as one and so will not allow an ORDER BY clause in this update.

However *@i* is a user defined variable and can be initialised by a separate SQL statement. If your query was 2 statements:-

```
SET @i:=0
UPDATE albums
SET id = IF(status='published', @i:=@i+1, 0)
ORDER BY albums.insert_date;
```

then that should do it (note, I have just assumed a random column name of insert_date to order the records by).

However many MySQL api's do not support multiple statements in a single query. As @i is a user variable it is related to the connection to the database. As such if you issue one query to initialise it and then a 2nd query (using the same connection) to process the UPDATE it should work.

If you are using php with MySQLi then you can use [mysqli-multi-query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to perform both in one go.

Comment: How would you integrate that ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I am not sure you can force the order. I don't think UPDATE supports and ORDER BY clause when multiple tables are used, and the sub query to initialise @i seems to be treated as a table. Think you would need to remove the join and use a separate `SET @i:=0;` before the query, and this would allow you to add a SORT to the UPDATE.

Comment: Hi Kickstart, thanks for the input. As you might have guessed from my question in the first place, i'm not that much of an expert. I'm really not asking for clear-cut answers, but can you please elaborate a bit on how to achieve this solution you're describing?

I'm not sure I'm using multible tables, just 'albums', in which 'status' and 'id' are columns

Comment: Added a bit of info on multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks Kickstart, I think I have it working now, having set and update in separate mysql queries.

Answer (score 0):

Kickstarts answer is almost what I need, only if an entree gets published it should always be gets the highest number. Right now it follows the database order, which is by date. Should I integrate an ORDER BY, or is there a different solution?

Thanks